# Python не видит существующей папки

Tags: python

Здравствуйте.
Есть такой набор файлов/папок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того, как загружаю все это на сервер и запускаю, выдает ошибку:

```
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output/image-out.jpg'
```

Хотя на компьютере все ок работает. Программа берет рисунок с папки images, добавляет текст и сохраняет в папку output, код:

```
img.save('output/image-out.jpg')
```

В чем проблема?

P.S Полный фрагмент кода где ошибка:

```
img = Image.open('images/{}.jpg'.format(random.randint(1,7)))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("fonts/impact.ttf", font_size)
draw.text((600-x, 160), answer_for_picture, (249, 19, 42), font=font)

img.save('output/image-out.jpg')
```

Comment: а файлик с картинкой там есть? и регистр символов такой же?

Comment: Код в студию! :)

Comment: KoVadim - нет файлика, он же должен динамически создаваться. gi9red - обновил фрагмент кода с ошибкой

Comment: Я вот думал, может, Python ищет не от директории,где храниться код, а от директории, где запущен пайтон? Но только почему тогда ошибка раньше не вышла, при поиске шрифта, шрифт оно же нашло...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему.

Проблема в том, что на heroku ( где я залил веб приложение) нельзя динамически создавать файлы без использования разных аддонов.